# Google place API Requesting multiple details JSON pages

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-places-api

In my PHP app I currently have two classes, one that can search nearby results from the google places api, and one that can get details from api place references.

I am returning twenty results from a  nearbysearch to the google places api and then looping over the results and passing each reference into the class that gets the place details api response.

The problem I'm having is it is very slow, is there any way of speeding up this process, maybe with concurrent requests to the api?

```
foreach($results['results'] as $result) {
    $namenospace = str_replace(' ', '_', $result['name']);
        $details = new placedetail($apiKey, $result['reference']);
        $placedetails = $details->getdetails();

        if($placedetails['result']['website']) {
            $website = $placedetails['result']['website'];
            $name = '<a href="'.$website.'" >'.$result['name'].'</a>';
        } else {
            $name =     $result['name'];
        }
        $html .= '<li class="restaurantoption dontsplit">';
        $html .=     '<input type="checkbox" class="restaurantcheckbox" name="restaurant[]" value="'.$result['name'].'" checked /><span class="resaurantname" >'.$name.'</span><br/>';
        $html .= '<div class="vicinity" ><small>'.$result['vicinity'].'</small></div>';
        $html .= '</li>';

}

    echo $html;


class GooglePlaces {

    private $_apiKey;
    public $errors = array();
    public $outputType = "json";

    private $_apiUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private $_query;
    private $_address;
    private $_apiCallType = "nearbysearch";
    private $_location;//REQUIRED  - This must be provided as lat,lng
    private $_radius;//REQUIRED
    private $_types;//optional
    private $sensor = 'false'; //REQUIRED
    private $_nextpage;

    public function __construct($_apiKey) {
       $this->_apiKey = $_apiKey;
    }

    public function SetLocation($_location) {
       $this->_location = $_location;
    }

    public function setApiUrl($_apiUrl) {
        $this->_apiUrl = $_apiUrl;  
    }

    public function SetRadius($_radius){
       $this->_radius = $_radius;
    }

     public function setNextPage ($_nextpage) {
        $this->_nextpage = $_nextpage;  
     }   

     public function setAddress($_address){
       $this->_address = $_address;
    }

     public function setSearchType($_apiCallType) {
        $this->_apiCallType = $_apiCallType;    
     }
    public function setQuery($_query) {
        $this->_query = $_query;    
    } 
    public function SetTypes($_types) {
       $this->_types = $_types;
    }
    public function getErrors() {
 return $this->errors;
    }

    public function searchPlaces() {
       $URLparams = "location=".$this->_location."&types=".$this->_types."&sensor=".$this->sensor."&rankby=distance";
       $URLToCall = $this->_apiUrl."/".$this->_apiCallType."/".$this->outputType."?key=".$this->_apiKey."&".$URLparams;
       $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($URLToCall),true);
       if($result['status'] == "OK") {
         return $result;
            } else { 
   $result['status'] = $this->errors;
  }
 }

    public function textsearchPlaces() {

             $URLparams = "&types=".$this->_types."&sensor=".$this->sensor."&query=".$this->_query."&rankby=distance";     
       $URLToCall = $this->_apiUrl."/".$this->_apiCallType."/".$this->outputType."?key=".$this->_apiKey."&".$URLparams;
       $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($URLToCall),true);
       if($result['status'] == "OK") {
         return $result;
         } else {
           $result['status'] = $this->errors;
         }
    }

  public function geocodeResult() {
        $URLparams = "address=".$this->_address."&sensor=".$this->sensor;  
       $URLToCall = $this->_apiUrl."/".$this->_apiCallType."/".$this->outputType."?".$URLparams;
       $URLToCall = str_replace(' ', '_', $URLToCall);
       $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($URLToCall), true);

         return $result;


}

public function loadmore() {
         $URLparams = "sensor=false&pagetoken=".trim($this->_nextpage);     
       $URLToCall = $this->_apiUrl."/".$this->_apiCallType."/".$this->outputType."?key=".$this->_apiKey."&".$URLparams;
       $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($URLToCall),true);
       if($result['status'] == "OK") { 
         return $result;

         } else {
           $result['status'] = $this->errors;
}
}
}


class placedetail {
    private $_key;
    private $_reference;
    private $_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json';

    public function __construct($_key, $_reference) {
       $this->_key = $_key;
       $this->_reference = $_reference; 
    }

    public function getdetails() {

       $URLparams = "reference=".$this->_reference."&sensor=false";
       $URLToCall = $this->_url."?key=".$this->_key."&".$URLparams;
       $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($URLToCall),true);
       if($result['status'] == "OK") {
         return $result;
        } else { 
            $result['status'] = $this->errors;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: did you find a solution?  i have the same question

Answer (score 0):

You could decrease number of API calls you make. Perhaps an option would be to fetch only one result and prefetch the rest of the results on user click. If caching the results is possible you could try that. I'm not an expert with Google places API, but perhaps you could fetch results with one API call instead of twenty. Number of API calls is your performance issue here.